# Run C file/executable from Java program

Tags: java, c, desktop-application

So I am new to "applied" programming in the sense of GUI's but I'm wanting to make a windows desktop application whose front end GUI is written in Java and where the back end will be computed in C. This is a heavy calculations based app so I want to use C for specific memory management and speed. However, how would I run a C file from inside a Java Program? I know that C is native to Linux so one can't compile a C file without GNU, which to my knowledge Windows does not have. So I was thinking that I could compile the C file on a computer with GNU and then transport the executable to run on any computer, would this work? How would I run a C executable from Java?

Comment: Don't "run a C executable from Java", starting a new shell or command process is kludge-y at best (in Java). Instead, you can use JNI or JNA (probably easier) to invoke native code directly from your Java process.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch even though this is a comment, it is exactly what I was looking for as an answer! Thanks

Comment: "I know that C is native to Linux so one can't compile a C file without GNU" MSVC is a thing that exists.

Comment: "So I was thinking that I could compile the C file on a computer with GNU and then transport the executable to run on any computer, would this work?" No. An executable can be built for Linux or for Windows, but not for both simultaneously.

Comment: Microsoft (before becoming known for Operating Systems like Windows) was famous for compilers and programming languages. Windows has multiple C compilers. From [Microsoft](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) and from others ([embarcadero](https://www.embarcadero.com/free-tools/ccompiler) still offers updated versions of the old Borland compiler tools and a free compiler). And at least two distributions of the GNU compiler: [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Java uses just-in-time compiling to turn compiled classes into native code at runtime.  You may want to try writing your calculations in Java, and verifying that the speed is in fact unacceptable, before going to the trouble of mixing Java and C.